# Adding legend to pandas.dataframe.plot when y option is used

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

If I plot a DataFrame as

```
df.plot()
```

then each line appears in the legend identifying which column it corresponds to, as it should be. However, if I plot it as

```
df.plot(x=0, y=[2,3])
```

then everything is plotted normally, however there is no legend identifying which line is which column.

I have tried

```
df.plot(x=0, y=[2,3], label=['2','3'])
df.plot(x=0, y=[2,3], legend=['2','3'])
```

but nothing works. The only workaround is to set

```
plt.legend(['2','3'])
```

afterwards, but I am not sure that the order of the legend list is the same order that pandas uses for plotting, so I don't know if the legend really matches the lines. Is there a way to make pandas plot the legend is this case?

I am using pandas 0.14.

Comment: Did you mean `y=[2,3]`? If so, the current version of pandas, 0.17, works as expected -- a legend is produced using, for example, `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,4)))`, `df.plot(x=0, y=[2,3])`.

Comment: Just fixed the typo. Thanks, @unutbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @unutbu writes, this works well for current versions of Pandas. On older versions, however, I found it easier just to "narrow down" the DataFrame to the relevant columns.

E.g., suppose you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 2], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [1, 3], 'd': [4, 5]})
```

Then to plot `'b'` and `'c'` as a function of `'a'`:

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']].plot(x='a');
```

This gives you the legend ordering for free.